# 3 Dimensional Dynamic Lookup - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lookup, array-formulas

I have created a test sheet on my personal account for reference. Please see that here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GYZsonJNP4Wdt2GqjOE2NUJZybRTp-WcXP13BP2okS0/edit?usp=sharing)

2 Tabs, both on the same sheet
"Lookup"
"Database"

Short Summary

- Need an array formula in cell "B2" on the Lookup tab that will
  populate down the whole row. The formula needs to pull the respective Datetime from row 2 on the Database tab, for the matching machine.

Conditions

1. Datetime from Database row 2 must be the closest value to NOW(). **EDIT: THIS CHECK MUST BE DONE FIRST, AND THEN COMPLETE CONDITION #2 STARTING FROM THE COLUMN FOUND.**
2. The value is the respective "Machine" row, must also be >0 (i.e. if the first column that meets condition 1 has "0" in the respective row, then it should move onto the next column, and so on until it finds a column in that respective row that has any number >0).

I have put a reference sheet to show you what the output should be and also highlighted the values that meet my conditions above (given the assumption that "Now()"="2/10/2021 14:37:00")

**UPDATED FORMULA**
Shout out to Player0, coming through strong on this one! Final formula posted here, which updates the assumed value for "NOW()" to be the actual dynamic value and rounds to the nearest 15 minutes!

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Database!B3:N7<>"", 
     Database!A3:A7&"×"&IF((Database!B2:N2-CEILING(NOW(),"00:15"))>-0.166678240741021,Database!B2:N2, "0")&"×"&ROW(Database!A3:A7)&"×"&
     ABS(Database!B2:N2-VALUE(CEILING(NOW(),"00:15")))&"×"&Database!B3:N7)), "×"), 3, 1, 4, 1), 
     "where Col2 <> 0 and Col5 <> 0 and Col2 is not null format Col2 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss'"), 2, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SORT(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Database!B3:N7>0, 
 Database!A3:A7&"×"&Database!B2:N2&"×"&ROW(Database!A3:A7)&"×"&
 ABS(Database!B2:N2-"2/10/2021 14:37:00"), )), "×")), 3, 1, 4, 1), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Database!B3:N7<>"", 
 Database!A3:A7&"×"&Database!B2:N2&"×"&ROW(Database!A3:A7)&"×"&
 ABS(Database!B2:N2-"2/10/2021 14:37:00")&"×"&Database!B3:N7)), "×"), 3, 1, 4, 1), 
 "where Col5 <> 0"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Database!B3:N7<>"", 
 Database!A3:A7&"×"&IF((VALUE(Database!B2:N2)-
 VALUE("2/10/2021 14:37:00"))>-0.166678240741021,Database!B2:N2, "¤")&"×"&ROW(Database!A3:A7)&"×"&
 ABS(Database!B2:N2-"2/10/2021 14:37:00")&"×"&Database!B3:N7)), "×"), 3, 1, 4, 1), 
 "where Col5 <> 0 and Col2 is not null"), 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Hey @player0
I tested it out and it does not function as intended. I duplicated my lookup tab and left your formula in there so you can see what I mean. It seems close, but something with pulling only the closest column to "NOW()" does not seem to be working. It is recognizing the >0 part, but it is pulling the 7:00 column instead of skipping that one since 14:37 is closer to the 15:00 value.

Comment: Hmm ok. Yeah sorry. I was comparing between 15:00 and 7:00, but the 15:00 values are obviously "0" so don't pass that validation. That said, I may need to tweak my request a little bit. Is it possible to have the date validation happen first and then move on to the "0" check? - So Basically it would find the closest date column first (regardless of it containing a "0") and then do the "0" validation starting from that column instead? This way it would find the 15:00 as being the closest, and then would proceed into the "0"'s, which would give me the result I am looking for.

Comment: I am going to keep playing in there as this still isn't quite there. We are still going "back in time" and pulling the 7:00 values. I could be wrong, but I feel like we need to make 2 calls here. The first call creates the list of all the dates and finds the one closest to NOW() and pulls the column number for that date. Then the second call pulls the list within a dynamic range (based on the column from the 1st call), excluding the 0's. This way it will not go "back" in time. I'll keep playing with it, but if you wanted to jump in again, feel free to! I'll post anything I discover.

Comment: Sorry, I added a comment into the sheet while you were in there, was hoping you might see it. I did actually see how to remove past events in there. The issue is that I want to remove past events only if they are further away than the following date column.

i.e. If we assume 14:36 like we have been. 7:00 is much further away that 15:00, so we would want to select 15:00. In this situation, just excluding past events would work fine. However if we instead assume 9:30. Then 7:00 is much closer than 15:00, so I would want to pull from the 7:00 value instead, even though it is in the past.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228597/discussion-between-rylan-grose-and-player0).